# My computer is freezing every 2 minutes

Tags: freeze, system

I have an old computer with Intel Pentium g2020 dual-core processor, 6 GB RAM, and an Nvidia GT710 graphic card . I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. I'm noticing it freezes every 2 minutes and then again becomes responsive, can anyone please help me?

Comment: open up a terminal by typing    ctrl + alt + t    then run command `top`  to show biggest cpu using processes this will also show free RAM system will become slow when either resource runs low

Comment: `top` is good, but `dstat` is better! Use `dstat -v --top-cpu --top-io --top-mem` and leave it running in a terminal. Keep an eye on it when the system locks up. Paste the 10 lines either side of the system freezing, into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the hd LED is ON during the freez and it is a real and longer (about 45 seconds) one (no actions visible and every input is broken), please check first the hd's health with a SMART tool like `Igsmartcontrol` or `smartmontools`. I know, it's more like a comment, but I haven't got enough reputation.